# Android GoogleDirection API

Tags: android, google-maps

I am troubling to use GoogleDirection API which find routes inside only Canada. I want to show route of driving on Google Map, so i am use this url.

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode
                + "&region=CA"; // Only In Canada
```

I called this url by using WebService and parse XML data from server and show the route on Map. But unfortunately, it not showed routes in only Canada.

For example, when i searched the route from Vancouver to Toronto, the route is passed in USA region.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: may be because both cities are in USA as well :)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue... perhaps clean up the formatting and clarify? Are you trying to find directions within Canada or outside of Canada? (It's a little unclear).

Comment: did you tried removing `region=CA` from your url?

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/Google-Directions-Android

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I am trying to find directions within only Canada.
The route is in only Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy full code :-)

You can use below class for showing directions :

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }

    return routes;
    }
    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as below:

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends Activity {

    static LatLng DEST = new LatLng(0, 0);
    static LatLng SOURCE = new LatLng(0, 0);
    private GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    String latitude , longitude;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        latitude = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("latitude");
        longitude = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("longitude");

        DEST = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
        SOURCE = new LatLng(gpsTracker.latitude,gpsTracker.longitude);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        if(map!=null){

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map


            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(DEST);
            markerPoints.add(SOURCE);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            Marker dest = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DEST)
                    .title("DEST")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            Marker source = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SOURCE)
            .title("SOURCE")
            .snippet("SOURCE is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));


            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            //                    if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
            //                        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
            //                        LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

            // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
            String url = getDirectionsUrl(DEST, SOURCE);

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);
            //                    }
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(DEST, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        }


    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }
    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("result",""+result);
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

            Log.e("result",""+result);
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, KishuDroid
But how can i get route in only Canada.
When i use this code, sometimes it is outside of Canada.

Comment: You need to pass latitude and longitude of canada only.

Comment: Yes, this is my origin and destination point. (50.725418,-113.978729) - (43.663057, -79.651703). This is from Vancouver to Toronto. But it is passed in USA region. How can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: just write down your points to below side and see what it shows :

http://www.distancesfrom.com/Map-from-to.aspx